# Can Himawari awake Tenseigan?

Tags: boruto

Himawari is daughter of hinata and naruto. Is it possible to awake tenseigan? In fact she awoke Byakugan without practise, Yeah I know it does not have any sense but ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will not be possible for Himawari to awaken the Tenseigan on her own. This is because the only way to awaken [the Tenseigan](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Tenseigan)

> is by combining Hamura's descendants chakra (within the Otsutsuki Clan) with the Byakugan (the Chakra of the Hyuga Clan).

Naruto is an Uzumaki, a clan that is closely related to the Senju Clan, and so he already possessed a bit of Hagoromo's Chakra (also being a reincarnation of Asura). However, that is not the same as Hamura's Chakra.

Note that Hagoromo is the first twin who possesed the Rinnengan, while Hamura possessed the Tenseigan and through blood line dilution, Hagoromo's two children inherited separately, his chakra and a lesser version of his eyes, which could be combined together to give his Original eyes. The same thing occurred with his younger twin.)

Comment: There's also the concept of "pure Byakugan", which was Toneri's preferred choice for awakening his Tenseigan (for unspecified reasons), since Hinata married outside the Huyga clan, her children can not be considered as pure  Hyugas and the same goes for their eyes.